# Can't contain table in div for chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Tried to contain a table within a div so that the width of the table doesn't exceed that of the containing DIV.

The table has one row, with two elements.  The second element is meant to be fixed length, the first element should wrap text so that the total table width not exceeding the width of div.

The following code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coder1020/u6dbadqm/)) doesn't work for Chrome browser (40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)), but it appears to work ok for Firefox browser (29.0).  Any idea how to make it work for both?   Thanks.

```
<html>
  <body>too long, code is in jsfiddle</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always use valid HTML markup https://validator.w3.org/, this will generally produce the expected output in most browsers. Other than that use tables for tabular data, use divs for layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used pre tag to maintain format of data, instead use table for that (too - table inside table).

Your problem would be solved by table-layout:fixed;, but as you are using pre and div(replaced this with span)in table, you will have to modify that, to make it work properly. I have removed span and pre for now

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6dbadqm/2/)

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin:0%;
    width:100%;
}
table
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;    
}

.middle {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1250px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="middle">
            <table border=1>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <span id="pktDetails">
                                <li class="main1" onclick="pktclick(this)" state="0">Frame 169: 759 bytes on wire (6072 bits), 759 bytes captured (6072 bits)</li>
                                <ul class="a" style="display:none">
                                    <li class="leaf">Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Arrival Time: Oct 11, 2011 06:51:36.170112000 CDT</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Epoch Time: 1318333896.170112000 seconds</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Frame Number: 169</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Frame Length: 759 bytes (6072 bits)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Capture Length: 759 bytes (6072 bits)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <li class="main1" onclick="pktclick(this)" state="0">Ethernet II, Src: be:08:f1:2f:fa:d4 (be:08:f1:2f:fa:d4), Dst: Cisco-Li_cb:9e:93 (98:fc:11:cb:9e:93)</li>
                                <ul class="a" style="display:none">
                                    <li class="leaf">Destination: Cisco-Li_cb:9e:93 (98:fc:11:cb:9e:93)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Source: be:08:f1:2f:fa:d4 (be:08:f1:2f:fa:d4)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Type: IP (0x0800)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <li class="main1" onclick="pktclick(this)" state="0">Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.20.0.165 (10.20.0.165), Dst: 157.55.15.126 (157.55.15.126)</li>
                                <ul class="a" style="display:none">
                                    <li class="leaf">Version: 4</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Header length: 20 bytes</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Total Length: 745</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Identification: 0x172b (5931)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Fragment offset: 0</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Time to live: 128</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Protocol: TCP (6)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Header checksum: 0x2976 [validation disabled]</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Source: 10.20.0.165 (10.20.0.165)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Destination: 157.55.15.126 (157.55.15.126)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <li class="main1" onclick="pktclick(this)" state="0">Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: jetform (1706), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 705</li>
                                <ul class="a" style="display:none">
                                    <li class="leaf">Source port: jetform (1706)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Destination port: http (80)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Sequence number: 1 (relative sequence number)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Acknowledgment number: 1 (relative ack number)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Header length: 20 bytes</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Window size value: 65535</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Checksum: 0xa88a [correct]</li>
                                </ul>
                                <li class="main1" onclick="pktclick(this)" state="1" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/capstar/res/images/node-opened-light.png);">Hypertext Transfer Protocol</li>
                                <ul class="a" style="display: block">
                                    <li class="leaf" style="word-wrap: break-word;">GET /ro.aspx?slv=&amp;tp=http%3A%2F%2Fuk.msn.com%2F%3Focid%3Diefvrt&amp;rid=c5023591b7fc483f960be9e7ef5a80ae&amp;di=179&amp;pi=7441&amp;ps=10225&amp;pn=UK+Homepage&amp;ch=MSFT&amp;evt=impr&amp;obs=msnhp_uk_pv HTTP/1.1\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Accept: */*\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Referer: http://uk.msn.com/?ocid=iefvrt\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Accept-Language: en-gb\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Host: ro-exp.uk.msn.com\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">Cookie: MC1=V=3&amp;GUID=6729f0aec2ee4eac88bda5dfc426e801; expid=id=74b7c0b300c3477d8ffdfb61563c9e4f&amp;bd=2011-10-10T22:05:55.246&amp;v=2; mh=MSFT; CC=IE; Sample=8; MUID=228E3701CDE567001C403586C9E5679A; expac=34II3a39_0803:C|; exprc=id=</li>
                                    <li class="leaf">\r\n</li>
                                </ul>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" width="500px">
0080  39 31 62 37 66 63 34 38 33 66 39 36 30 62 65 39   91b7fc483f960be9
0090  65 37 65 66 35 61 38 30 61 65 26 64 69 3d 31 37   e7ef5a80ae&amp;di=17
00a0  39 26 70 69 3d 37 34 34 31 26 70 73 3d 31 30 32   9&amp;pi=7441&amp;ps=102
00b0  32 35 26 70 6e 3d 55 4b 2b 48 6f 6d 65 70 61 67   25&amp;pn=UK+Homepag


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wait, why are you telling OP not to use divs...?

Comment: Thanks @divy3993, based on your revision, I added style for table `style="width:100%;overflow:auto;table-layout:fixed;"` and it took care of my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The two first elements inside div.middle have an overflow:auto, if you just set the overflow to initial or don't set overflow, gonna work like in firefox.

```
<body>
   <div class="middle">
      <div   style="overflow: initial;">
      <table style="overflow: initial;">
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6dbadqm/5/)

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Dantas for the suggestion, I tried it, but table css style `style="width:100%;overflow:auto;table-layout:fixed;"` works better in my cases.  Did some googling, don't see an option for overflow called "inicial", guess you meant to use "initial"?

Comment: Ops, sorry it's "initial", I translated to portuguese, already edit my answer, thanks

Comment: Yeah, it makes more sense :-)  According to what I read,  "initial" means default value.